# What happens when the leader for a partition is separated from other producers?

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a setup, where in we have a cluster of nodes N1, N2 and N3. Kafka also runs in cluster modes in these 3 nodes as well. For a particular topic partition , N2 is the leader. As a part of the testing, we separate N1 from both N2 and N3. When a producer from N1 is posting to the topic, exception is thrown.

To my understanding,

`Each partition has one server which acts as the "leader" and zero or more servers which act as "followers". The leader handles all read and write requests for the partition while the followers passively replicate the leader. If the leader fails, one of the followers will automatically become the new leader. Each server acts as a leader for some of its partitions and a follower for others so load is well balanced within the cluster.`

If that is the case should not N1 become the leader of the topic and let the content be posted and continue? I can understand if it would thrown an exception that there is no necessary quorum and drop, but the below exception seems to make the kafka behavior different from my understanding. I see an issue reported to kafka ( https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-3686) However there the producer is a different node and the three nodes in the cluster seem to be connected. ( as I infer) which is different from what I face. Can someone explain what is happening?

java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException

```
    at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.send(BlockingChannel.scala:112)

    at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.liftedTree1$1(SimpleConsumer.scala:101)

    at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.kafka$consumer$SimpleConsumer$$sendRequest(SimpleConsumer.scala:86)

    at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer$$anonfun$fetch$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(SimpleConsumer.scala:135)

    at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer$$anonfun$fetch$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(SimpleConsumer.scala:135)

    at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer$$anonfun$fetch$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(SimpleConsumer.scala:135)

    at kafka.metrics.KafkaTimer.time(KafkaTimer.scala:31)

    at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer$$anonfun$fetch$1.apply$mcV$sp(SimpleConsumer.scala:134)

    at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer$$anonfun$fetch$1.apply(SimpleConsumer.scala:134)

    at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer$$anonfun$fetch$1.apply(SimpleConsumer.scala:134)

    at kafka.metrics.KafkaTimer.time(KafkaTimer.scala:31)

    at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.fetch(SimpleConsumer.scala:133)

    at kafka.consumer.ConsumerFetcherThread.fetch(ConsumerFetcherThread.scala:117)

    at kafka.consumer.ConsumerFetcherThread.fetch(ConsumerFetcherThread.scala:36)

    at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherThread.processFetchRequest(AbstractFetcherThread.scala:149)

    at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherThread.doWork(AbstractFetcherThread.scala:113)

    at kafka.utils.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.scala:64)
```

Comment: Producers shouldn't be running on the brokers anyway